# MongoDB Path Change?

Tags: mongodb

My server went down from an electrical failure and for a few horrifying seconds, I thought I'd lost all MongoDB data.  I then realized that when the server restarted, mongo automatically restarted without the --dbpath option.

What I can't figure out is why, even though my mongodb.conf has the dbpath set to /var/lib/mongodb, mongo looked for the db files in /data/db on startup.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/data/db` is the default path that `mongod` will look for data files in if it is started with no options. Does your startup script instruct `mongod` to load the correct config file? If not, that would explain this behavior.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going for several weeks ago.  Sorry for not updating the thread sooner - and thanks for your contribution = )

Answer (score 3):

When was the last time you updated Mongod on your system? and how did you update it?

Depending how you installed / updated Mongod it could happen that either the /etc/init.d/mongo script or the /etc/mongo.conf files could be overwritten.

Or somebody edited those files a long time ago, and this is the first time Mongo got restarted, and now it looks like there's suddenly a change.

I haven't seen either of those two things happen in a long time (but if you're using Gentoo, you would probably see this happen)

What OS do you use?

It's a good idea to keep backups of those files...

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely ensure that your init script for Mongo includes the full pathname to the data directory. Here is a snippet of what we use in our production deployment:

```
ulimit -s unlimited

MONGO_USER=mongo
MONGO_HOME=/opt/mongo
MONGO_DATA=/san2/data
MONGO_LOGS=/home/mongo/logs


start() {
    su $MONGO_USER -c "$MONGO_HOME/bin/mongod  --master --fork --logpath $MONGO_LOGS/mongodb.log --logappend --dbpath $MONGO_DATA  --maxConns 2400"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the startup options in `/etc/default/mongodb` most likely those will be set to the default path of `/data/db` instead of the one you selected when you started it up manually.